# SQL and sqlite3 both return correct results for `count(*)`. SQLite for Android always returns 1. How can this be? Why isn't it a bug?

Tags: android, sqlite

Please consider this program segment:

```
Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, mColumns, null, null,null, null, null);
int nRows = cursor.getCount();
```

Note from `Log` output below that this returns the correct number of rows to `nRows`--86000.

Here is what any SQL-savvy developer would expect to also return 86000 to `x`:

```
Cursor c2 = mDatabase.rawQuery("select count(*) from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
int x = c2.getCount();
```

Here's why they would expect that--sqlite3.exe produces that result:

```
sqlite> select count(*) from wordlist;
86000
```

However, the result returned to `x` by Android SQLite is ***1***.

Here's the `Log` statement that is at the bottom of the code above:

``````
Log.w("`````dbDump","rows: " + nRows + " or is it " + x + " rows?");
``````

Here's its output:

``````
W/`````dbDump: rows: 86000 or is it 1 rows?
``````

The answer is that the database has 86000 rows, not 1.

My question is simple (and is stated in the Title):

Why would anyone trying (even if loosely) to simulate SQL design a commonly-used function such as `count(*)` to always return the same value?

If you choose to downvote me, go ahead, but answer that question, please. It seems like a bug because no one would expect a constant result to always be returned by any function.

Gripes that resemble questions:

You'd expect 1 to always be returned if this really is documented somewhere and you found it. In that case, where? (URL, please?)

Is there really a use for `count(*)` to always return 1? (I suppose an answer could be that to remove it or make it work right would require a major rewrite.)

If you do not think that these are legitimate questions, then you didn't spend too long a time trying to find out what you were doing wrong, which, as it turns out, was simply using SQL knowledge and `rawQuery`.

Comment: "You'd expect 1 to always be returned if this really is documented somewhere and you found it. In that case, where? (URL, please?)" -- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount() As documented there, `getCount()` "Returns the numbers of rows in the cursor". It does not return the value of some column for some row from the `Cursor`.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question? What happened to the earlier version of it?

Comment: @Iaalto--I had asked for help with my non-working code in my previous question. That's not what I'm asking here. I'm now asking why the heck would `select count(*) from wordlist` always return 1 in AS SQLite when the same statement returns 86000 (rows in table) in sqlite3.exe. I asked for my previous post to be deleted since the whole thing was far too confusing (at least to me) to be of any use.

Comment: @laalto--BTW, my words "same statement" in my previous comment belie the whole problem I was having, both in previous and this post. I was comparing a `select` statement and a `Cursor` definition but expecting same results merely by presence of `count(*)`. Right now I can't believe I was that ... whatever. I was comparing Apples and Dells and expecting the same OS just because both have keyboards.

Comment: The original version of this question did not seem too bad to me, even if it was based on a misunderstanding of code, but it appears to have been modified with so much stream-of-consciousness writing that the current state is unreadable. I think it is very closable in its present condition, so I will make a suggested rollback to avoid having to do that. If you are sure you want it gone, ping me and I can cast a close vote, but as I say, the original seemed OK (am not an Android programmer).

Comment: @halfer--it wasn't bad except for my glowing misunderstanding, which I could tolerate--we all make mistakes. I had to kill it because of the treatment I inflicted upon a replier. In my defense, instead of him just asking "what don't you understand" and ignoring my request for documentation and being defensive (we both were, especially me) or just restating his original answer (which was correct), if he had just put it into words such as are on this page, I wouldn't have made an ass of myself and I wouldn't have requested deletion. But it had to go. If I could find a copy, I'd post it for you,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code

```
Cursor c2 = mDatabase.rawQuery("select count(*) from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
```

gives you **one row with one column** and `count(*)` is the value at position [0, 0].

`Cursor.getCount()` returns number of rows in the result, in this particular case that's 1.

To get the value you'd call

```
c2.moveToFirst(); // Move to first row.
int count = c2.getInt(0); // Get value as integer from first column of current row.
```

Comment: One should mention [longForQuery()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#longForQuery(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) and [queryNumEntries()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String)).